# Calling C from Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm new to objective c & c. I'm trying to use this [random generator c library](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html) in an objective c program. My understanding is that objective c is a strict superset of c so this should be possible.

My code compiles and runs but I get a lot of warnings.

- warning: implicit declaration of function 'mt_seed32'
- warning: implicit declaration of function 'mt_lrand'
- warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'mt_seed32' is invalid in C99
- warning: Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'mt_lrand' is invalid in C99
- warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing `uint32_t *` (aka `unsigned int *`) with an expression of type `int`

I have not imported the C header file to the objective c class - it just finds it. If I import it I get duplicate method errors.

C library header file:

```
extern void     mt_seed32(uint32_t seed);

extern uint32_t     mt_lrand(void);
```

Code to call it: [I've tried calling it with [self method()] but that crashes

```
mt_seed32(3);

uint32_t *i = mt_lrand();
```

Can anyone tell me how too get rid of these warnings?

Comment: You get the warnings because you haven’t included the C header file that declares those functions. Can you post the error messages you get when you include the header file?

Comment: If I add #include "RandomGenerator.h" to the top of the file I get this error:

ld: duplicate symbol _mts_lrand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last compiler error happens because `mt_lrand();` returns an int, not a pointer to an int. Therefore, the last line should be

```
uint32_t i = mt_lrand();
```

All the other errors are due to the fact that you did not `#include` the library header. Could you please post the errors that occur when you do include the library header?

Answer (score 2):

Messages such as `implicit declaration of function 'mt_seed32'` usually pop up, when you use a function before it was defined. See example.

```
void foo() {
    //do stuff
    bar(); //call bar that was declared later
}

void bar() {
    ...
}
```

This may happen if you forgot to include the header file, or you included it after you used functions declared in that header file. Another fix is to declare a function prototype before usage.

Also you assign your random number to a pointer to uint32_t. Is this what you really want?
If not, then you must remove `*` from your declaration: `uint32_t i = mt_lrand();`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix my problem by changing file type from '.m' to '.mm'. This causes the compiler to use obj c++ not obj c. It removes the warnings but I'm not sure if I've fixed the underlying issues

[Solution – Duplicate Symbol](http://ccdosage.com/solution-duplicate-symbol-failed-with-exit-code-1/)

Comment: That fixes the problem because C++ treats inline functions differently. From a very brief glance, the underlying cause seems to be how the various compatibility macros for inline/extern keywords and for the location of the actual function definitions (`MT_INLINE/MT_EXTERN/MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER`) are set up in this library.