# iOS Code Protection - C Static Library or Objective-C Framework?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

I have some calculation algorithms that I need to send to my client for testing. I am asked to prevent my client from reverse engineering the algorithm. I am thinking that I have 2 choices:

1. Wrapping the calculation in Objective-C framework, in which I
   could make some HTTPS request to my server periodically, the
   framework will only do calculation if the server allows.
2. Wrapping the calculation in C program and compile into .a static
   library. It is a plain C library, so I think will be very difficult
   to make HTTPS request. But I also read that C static library is more
   difficult to break relative to dynamic framework.

I understand that there are no 100% security, I just want to know in terms of security which option is better? And please also suggest if there are any other ways to secure frameworks / static libraries?

Comment: You want calculations to be performed on the client computer, but you do not want a person with access to the client computer to be able to reverse engineer the calculations? There are some theoretical ways operations can be performed on encrypted data so that the person performing the operations cannot feasibly discern the unencrypted data, but they are likely beyond what you really want to do. What is the real situation here? If the client is going to send results of the calculations back to the server, you cannot trust them.

Comment: Generally, any calculations that are performed on a client computer should be regarded as exposed to the world, and trying to conceal them is not a feasible goal in most situations. The approaches you describe would result in nuisance to an attacker, but they would be only minor nuisances to experienced attackers and could not be considered secure.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the deliverable to your client in this context is just the result of the algorithm (and not the actual implementation of the algorithm). Once way to achieve it is by implementing the algorithm on your server (using C, Node.js, Python, etc.) and then expose it via an HTTP/s API. Then from your iOS app/framework/static library, you pass the required parameters as inputs via a HTTP request, perform the computation on your server and return the results.

Comment: Yes, I agree building a server provide the best protection. However, this is not feasible because the calculation has to be performed real-time

Comment: In which case you can go with option 1 but implement the algorithm (secure part) in C and the HTTP calls in Objective C. Then just call your C methods from Obj C. This post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131372/calling-c-from-objective-c